# Visualization & Dashboard return no results found, while discover tab successfully displays results?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, visualization, kibana, dashboard

I have a problem with Kibana: Dashboard and visualizations don't show any results!

As you can see in this screenshot, in the discover tab I get some results! Which means data exists in my index "as-*". right? But I used a trick in order to display this data :

1) I changed the range to "Today" ==> it shows no result found !

2) I clicked "New" button ==> then i get my data displayed!
Is there an other way "more proper" to get data displayed?

[image: Discover Tab]

Then in the my dashboard (or visualization) I can't get any results!! even if the range is the same as discover tab!

[image: Dashboard Tab]

I restarted Kibana ==> no changes!
I deleted as-* then I created it => no changes!

I'm using Curator to create daily index and logstash to index the data into ES!

I'm stuck here ! I ll be glad if you can help me figure it out !
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly new to elasticsearch and Kibana, but here are three mistakes that I made in the past:

1. Are you using the correct index? Make sure that the index you have chosen for the logs that are displayed on the visualise page and for the actual visualisations is the same.
2. Correct timeperiod: does the time period you have chosen contain the data you are looking for? Or did you happen to have zero logs during that time?
3. Correct filters and aggregations: when you were making the visualisations, did they show any results? Or were they empty from the beginning? Maybe one of your filters or aggregations is wrong and it's excluding the results you're expecting to see.

Not sure if this is any help, hope you've sold the problem by now :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can see information in "discover", it means that kibana has connected to the database, and that the database has information. You shouldn't have to click the "New" button to see information in the discover view. I believe the "New" button in the "discover" page is used to create a new search.

Maybe try zooming on the time period of the data on the "discover" page, or 
try checking the systems logs to see if logstash is successfully pushing information to Elasticsearch.

With Kibana, dashboards are made up of visualisations, and visulations are made up of searches.

The "No results found" on the dashboard page, shown in your second page is due to the visualisation having no results. I guess you imported visulations into Kibana.

I hope that helps.